# Show top n rows for every column in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have the following sample CSV.

```
,cid1,cid2,cid3
rid1,0.1,0.4,0.3
rid2,1.0,0.1,0.5
rid3,0.2,0.5,0.1
rid4,0.3,0.4,0.8
rid5,0.2,0.3,0.7
rid6,0.9,0.2,0.1
rid7,0.4,0.8,0.9
rid8,0.6,0.5,0.7
rid9,0.3,0.9,0.4
```

I want to show *n* rows with the highest value for every column in the file. Ideally, I would like to get the following output (for *n* = 3).

```
cid1  rid2  1.0
cid1  rid6  0.9
cid1  rid8  0.6
                    # Blank lines separating columns are optional.
cid2  rid9  0.9
cid2  rid7  0.8
cid2  rid8  0.5

cid3  rid7  0.9
cid3  rid4  0.8
cid3  rid8  0.7
```

This is what I have so far.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("input.csv", index_col=0)
n = 3

for col in df:
    print(col)
    print(df.sort_values(col, ascending=False)[:n][col].to_string())
```

which gives me almost what I want.

```
cid1
rid2    1.0
rid6    0.9
rid8    0.6
cid2
rid9    0.9
rid7    0.8
rid3    0.5
cid3
rid7    0.9
rid4    0.8
rid5    0.7
```

Also, there is a small issue with `cid2`, for which `rid8` and `rid3` have the same value of `0.5`. In that case, it would be perfect to show them both in separate lines, but I'm aware it will probably complicate the code much further so I would be happy with the basic solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for `GroupBy.nlargest`?

```
df.unstack().groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).nlargest(3)
 
cid1  rid2    1.0
      rid6    0.9
      rid8    0.6
cid2  rid9    0.9
      rid7    0.8
      rid3    0.5
cid3  rid7    0.9
      rid4    0.8
      rid5    0.7
dtype: float64
```

---

Trying to mirror OP's "expected" result:

```
print(df.unstack()
        .groupby(level=0, group_keys=False)
        .nlargest(3)
        .reset_index()
        .to_string(header=None, index=False))

cid1 rid2 1.0
cid1 rid6 0.9
cid1 rid8 0.6
cid2 rid9 0.9
cid2 rid7 0.8
cid2 rid3 0.5
cid3 rid7 0.9
cid3 rid4 0.8
cid3 rid5 0.7
```

Comment: For some wierd reason, I assumed `nlargest` wasn't directly supported in a grouper object. Lost some practice :-)

Comment: @anky I also go out of practice but I keep reading my old answers every now and then so I remember :-)

Comment: You guys are sorcerers to make it so compact. Would it take much effort to convert this output to the output I presented in the question?

Comment: @sherlock85 I tried to get close, but I don't think I can add blank lines between the groups, sorry.

Comment: @sherlock85 All code has already been included in the answer. Please feel free to request clarification on any of the finer points. Thanks!

Comment: @cs95 Thank you! This is what I was looking for. Last quick question (I know it's a little outside of the scope of this question). Is there a quick way to see the same output format for all values (not only top 3) that are for example >= 0.5? Or should I post a new question for this task?

Comment: @sherlock85 sooo are you looking to filter the unstacked series on some condition? How about `s = df.unstack(); print (s[s >= .5])`.

Comment: @cs95 This worked but didn't get the expected output format as in your answer.

Comment: @sherlock85 Surely you can use my current answer to get what you want? Starting with `s[s >= .5]` you would add the `reset_index` and `to_string` call as well to get your output.

Comment: @cs95 I'm so sorry to be a bother. But the sorting doesn't work according to the column. s = df.unstack(); print(s[s >= .3].reset_index().to_string(header=None, index=False))

Comment: @sherlock85 it wasn't clear to me you wanted the result sorted, sorry. Do you want to open a new question, in that case? Lets make sure we have all of your requirements before attempting to tackle this further. Cheers.

Comment: @rs95 Sorry, it's my bad I didn't provide all the requirements. I will open a new question.