# Show all cells in Pandas dataframe that satisfy certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have the following sample CSV file.

```
,cid1,cid2,cid3
rid1,0.1,0.4,0.3
rid2,1.0,0.1,0.5
rid3,0.2,0.5,0.1
rid4,0.3,0.4,0.8
rid5,0.2,0.3,0.7
rid6,0.9,0.2,0.1
rid7,0.4,0.8,0.9
rid8,0.6,0.5,0.7
rid9,0.3,0.9,0.4
```

I want to show all cells that are greater than 0.4 in the following format:

```
 cid1  rid2  1.0       # Values are descending based on the first column.
 cid1  rid6  0.9
 cid1  rid8  0.6
                       # Blank lines are only for visibility (I don't need them)
 cid2  rid9  0.9
 cid2  rid7  0.8
 cid2  rid3  0.5
 cid2  rid8  0.5

 cid3  rid7  0.9
 cid3  rid4  0.8
 cid3  rid5  0.7
 cid3  rid8  0.7
 cid3  rid2  0.5
```

So far I have the following code, which I created based on the comments from @rs95 in [my last similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65438075/show-top-n-rows-for-every-column-in-pandas-data-frame). However, I am too dumb to make it work. The code does not sort values in descending order per column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("input.csv", index_col=0)
min_score = 0.4

s = df.unstack()
print(s[s >= min_score]
        .reset_index()
        .to_string(header=None, index=False))
```

Comment: the link you mentioned has the complete the solution. Where are you facing trouble?

Comment: @RajatMishra The problem is the values in the output are not sorted per column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", index_col=0)
min_score = 0.4

s = df.unstack()
s = s[s >= min_score].reset_index().sort_values(["level_0", 0], ascending=[True, False])

print(s.to_string(header=None, index=False))
```

Output:

```
 cid1  rid2  1.0
 cid1  rid6  0.9
 cid1  rid8  0.6
 cid1  rid7  0.4
 cid2  rid9  0.9
 cid2  rid7  0.8
 cid2  rid3  0.5
 cid2  rid8  0.5
 cid2  rid1  0.4
 cid2  rid4  0.4
 cid3  rid7  0.9
 cid3  rid4  0.8
 cid3  rid5  0.7
 cid3  rid8  0.7
 cid3  rid2  0.5
 cid3  rid9  0.4
```

Explanation for the

```
.sort_values(["level_0", 0], ascending=[True, False])
```

The first argument is the `by` argument, where we decide which columns we want to sort the `DataFrame` by. Since the `"level_0"` is put in the list before, `0`, the columns will be sorted by the `"level_0"` column first.

The `ascending` argument let's us decide whether each element in the `by` list should be sorted in ascending order, or descending order.